# sql query grouping with condition

Tags: sql, grouping

there is a table with employee numbers(column) and monthy payments(column)with paramcode(column) as basic, vda etc..  and amounts(column) corresponding to each paramcode.

```
empno.  month  paramcode amount
1        jan     basic     788
1        feb      vda      232
1        march     pf      12
```

now this is actual question

Write a query to display sum of BASIC + VDA + HRA for an employee Payment where the employee has been paid PF in the payment

(do not use sub queries , Joins and Set operators)

My answer is

```
SELECT EmployeeNumber,paramcode, SUM(ActualAmount) AS S FROM pay
WHERE ParamCode IN ('BASIC','VDA','HRA','pf') 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((EmployeeNumber,ParamCode))
ORDER BY EmployeeNumber
```

but i want to eliminate the employee numbers with param code as 'pf'

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right use SQL except tag like this  except ParamCode in ('pf')

Answer (score 0):

You are actually adding 'PF' in ParamCode, this is the correct query:

```
SELECT EmployeeNumber,paramcode, SUM(ActualAmount) AS S FROM pay
WHERE ParamCode IN ('BASIC','VDA','HRA') 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((EmployeeNumber,ParamCode))
ORDER BY EmployeeNumber
```